# Filling between circles in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

I want to fill region between two half circles using tikz. Here is what I  tried and failed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-, ] (-3,0) --(-0.4,0);
\draw [-, ] (0.4,0) --(3,0);
\fill[gray!15]  ( -3,-3) |- (-0.4,0) arc (-180:0:4mm)-- (3,0) -| 
 (3,-3);
\draw [blue,thick,domain=180:360] plot ({.4*cos(\x)}, {.4*sin(\x)});
\draw [blue,thick,domain=180:360] plot ({3*cos(\x)}, {3*sin(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do post your \documentclass[]{} to \end{document}@Physics Moron

Comment: your MWE is still  not complete :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-]  ( -3,0) -- (-0.4,0)
           (0.4,0) -- (3,0);
\fill[gray!15]  (-3,0)  -- (-0.4,0) arc (-180:0: 4mm) 
                        -- (3,0)    arc (0:-180:30mm); % <-- changed
\draw [blue,thick,domain=180:360] plot ({.4*cos(\x)}, {.4*sin(\x)});
\draw [blue,thick,domain=180:360] plot ({ 3*cos(\x)}, { 3*sin(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Addendum:
Considering *Paul Gaborit* comment below, your MWE can be simplified and improved with use `arc` instead to draw `plot` function:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-]   ( -3,0) -- (-0.4,0)
            (0.4,0) -- (3,0);
\fill[gray!15]      (-3,0) -- (-0.4,0) arc (-180:0: 4mm)
                           -- (3,0)    arc (0:-180:30mm); 
\draw[blue,thick]   (.4,0) arc (0:-180: 4mm); % <-- changed
\draw[blue,thick]   ( 3,0) arc (0:-180:30mm); % <-- changed
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may replace the `plot` operations by `arc` operations... ;-)

Comment: yes, as is done in drawing fill.  added in answer (and also corrected some superfluous in the first code.